# Query display names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a 2 columns in a SQL Server table.

One is characters like 'Attn: firstname lastname', and the other column  has a number associated with that person.

I can't figure out how to query them so the info comes out as:

```
Lastname, Firstname - number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in SQL Server you can do this

```
Select Col1 + ' - ' + Col2
From dbo.{Table}
Where {Conditions}
```

If you mean you need to drop the "attn:" you can do something like this

```
Select substring(Col1, 5,len(Col1)-5) + ' - ' + Col2
From dbo.{Table}
Where {Conditions}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the index of ':', you can do something like this

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(Col1, (LEN(Col1) - CHARINDEX(':', Col1)-1)),' ',', ') + ' - ' + Col2
```

To test this you can run the following

```
 DECLARE @column1string AS VARCHAR(30), @column2number AS VARCHAR(10)
 SET @column1string = 'Attn: Firstname Lastname'
 SET @column2number = '12345678'

 SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(@column1string, (LEN(@column1string) - CHARINDEX(':', @column1string)-1)),' ',', ') + ' - ' + @column2number
```